# Trying to use Foundation Tooltips but failing

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I've seen the Foundation Tooltips on w3schools
http://www.w3schools.com/foundation/foundation_tooltips.asp

I've downloaded the foundation.css, foundation.min.css and modernizer.js.  I already have jquery set-up and working on my site.

But the tool tips aren't working, I've created an example which also doesn't work.  https://jsfiddle.net/SimonPlatten/x6ftzrvf/1/

In my code:

```
var strTooltip = "hello&lt;br />line2";
strEntry += "<span data-tooltip class=\"has-tip radius\""
               + " title=\"" + strTooltip + "\">Sometext</span>";
$(page).append(strEntry);
```

If I take the exact tool tip that I have in the above example and try it on the w3schools example it works perfectly, but I can't see what I'm missing.

Comment: The tooltips seem to work fine in that fiddle on my end. What's your browser/OS?

Comment: It didn't work in jsfiddle because you loaded foundation.js library over HTTP. I fixed it. See now, works like a charm: https://jsfiddle.net/x6ftzrvf/2/

Comment: Thank you I see that it works but what have you done?

Comment: I can see that it works, but I can't see how its different from my original?

Comment: Looking at my original I can see that I loaded it with http and you have used https, but why would this make any difference?  On my local node set-up I only have http.

Comment: @Splatten jsfiddle loads in HTTPS so when you include HTTP resource it will be blocked. If you only use HTTP on your server then something else is going on. Make sure you included all the needed libraries - see answer below. Also check browser console (hit F12) for any errors.

Comment: Thanks, I've implemented another solution now, displaying a context panel when I hover over the content.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Foundation documentation directly, w3schools seems to be outdated, according to the docs

Link to documentation  http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/tooltips.html

> It's easy to configure tooltips using our Javascript. You can use
>   data-attributes or plain old Javascript. **Make sure jquery.js,
>   foundation.js, and foundation.tooltip.js** have been included on your
>   page before continuing. For example, add the following before the
>   closing `<body>` tag:

You seem to be missing foundation.tooltip.js

Comment: On the original the foundation.tooltip.js isn't referenced either, I believe that foundation.min.js has everything packaged in it.